# Image in TableView Cell not shown

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a UISplitView. The TableView should show an image and a label. I set the identifier in the storyboard and also in the function cellForRowAtIndexPath. I wrote a class for the outlets of the cell. But the image and the label are not shown...Could you please help me?
The cells are created, I have tested it with the light gray background color...

Thats my class declaration:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

private let categories: [String] = ["Alle", "Apéritif", "Digestif", "Long Drinks", "Tageskarte", "Favoriten", "Suche"]
private let images: [String] = ["Alle.jpeg", "americano.jpg", "brandy alexander.jpg", "bellini.jpg", "Tageskarte.jpg", "Favoriten.jpg", "suche.jpg"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Cocktails"
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 100.0
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.labelStartpage.text = categories[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageViewStartpage.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

}

Thats the outlet class:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageViewStartpage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var labelStartpage: UILabel!
```

}

Identifier is set [Identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKuLh.png)
Class is also set [Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls43n.png)

Comment: did you add the datasource and delegate to self ?

Comment: I don't want to "see images". If you want help with your code, show your code. Copy it and paste it in right here.

Comment: I added the code.
Datasource and delegate was set by drag & drop

Answer (score -2):

Add datasource and delegate in your table view controller or bind it using drag and drop.
It solve your problem.

Comment: I set datasource and delegate by drag & drop and also coded but nothing has changed